# How to disable emoji substitution for pictographs/symbols in special characters?

Tags: macos, internationalization, text-input, emoji

When I try to insert a special character/symbol/pictograph that has an emoji equivalent, it always changes into the emoji instead. Is there a way to make it not do this? I am not asking about how to disable emoji substitution when typing smileys in Messages. This is happening wherever I try to insert a symbol--in Safari, TextEdit, and I even tried symbol and text substitution in System Preferences but the symbols turned into emoji there also.

Comment: @bmike I don't think this is quite a duplicate; this is asking about single characters with emoji equivalents, not character sequences getting replaced by emoji characters.

Comment: I can't post this as an actual answer, but you can put U+FE0F after any character to make it show up as non-emoji.